# For the differentiation of $x^{\frac23} + y^{\frac23} = a^{\frac23}$, why is the substitution $x = a \cos^3\theta$ legal?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

While looking at a solution for finding the derivative of $x^{\frac23} + y^{\frac23} = a^{\frac23}$, the book uses:

Let $x = a \cos^3\theta$ and $y = a\sin^3\theta$

However, why would that substitution be legal? $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ only range between $-1$ and $1$, which would imply that $x$ is somewhere between $a\cdot (-1)$ and $a\cdot (1)$ but $x$ could be $2a$ or $3a$ or any other value of multiplication by $a$ aswell. Why is the above substitution legal?

Comment: What is the variable of differentiation?

Comment: Please include the source of the exercise.

Comment: $y^{2/3}=(y^{1/3})^2\geq0$, so $x\leq a$

Comment: You have $(x^{1/3})^2+(y^{1/3})^2=(a^{1/3})^2$, so $x^{1/3}=a^{1/3}\cos(\theta),y^{1/3}=a^{1/3}\sin(\theta)$ is the appropriate substitution.

Comment: Try $x= bcos^3(\theta)$ where b is a constant and see where that takes you.

Comment: No, $x$ can't just be *anything*. Both $x$ and $y$ must be in the range $[-a,a]$, because otherwise the LHS would exceed $a^{2/3}$ and so couldn't equal the RHS.

Comment: @dbanet Unfortunately that's all there is to it. The exact words of the excercise are "Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, if $x^{\frac23} + y^{\frac23} = a^{\frac23}$". The exercise itself is from a local school textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid because lets say you want $x$ to be $8a$, then

$(8a)^{\frac 2 3} + y^{\frac 2 3}=a^{\frac 2 3}$

$y^{\frac 2 3}=-3a^{\frac 2 3}$
Has no real solution for $y$ because the left hand side is a square and the right hand side is a negative number.

The idea is the same for the parametrization for the unit circle, $x^2+y^2=1$, as both $x$ and $y$ can only range between $0$ to $1$, so we can let $x=cos\theta$ and $y=sin\theta$

Comment: I think i get the idea, but that's still just an example. Can you provide a more rigid proof that x and y must lie between a and -a?

Comment: We can try writing $y$ in terms of $x$, $y=\pm sqrt{(a^{2/3}-x^{2/3})^3}$ (plus or minus is need because $y$ can be a negative number but square root will only give you the positive one). Then since we are taking square root of an expression, that means the expression must be non negative, otherwise the $y$ value would be imaginary. So $a^{2/3}-x^{2/3}\geq 0$, which gives us $a^2\geq x^2$ , $0\geq (x-a)(x+a)$. So either only one of $0\geq x+a$ or $0\geq x-a$, but when $-a> x$, both $(x-a)$ and $(x+a)$ are positive. So the range of x must lie between $a\geq x\geq -a$. Similarly,$a\geq y\geq -a$